# Tensorflow TextVectorization: convert the predicted text back to a human readable string

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, vectorization, raw-input

I have developed a model that generates a new world that follows a sequence. The model successfully outputs a prediction, but I'm unable to use it as it is vectorized.

I use `tensorflow.keras.layers.TextVectorization` to vectorize the text:

```
text_vectorizer = layers.TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=len_shared_vocabulary,
    output_mode="int",
    output_sequence_length=max_inputs_length,
    vocabulary=shared_vocabulary,
)
```

Then I do:

```
vectorized_text = text_vectorizer(text)
```

And I feed the data to the model:

```
input = Input(shape=(max_inputs_length), name='input')
inputs_arr.append(input)

# ...layers

concatenated = layers.concatenate(layers_arr, axis=-1)

output_tensor = layers.Dense(1, activation='softsign')(concatenated)

model = Model(inputs_arr, output_tensor)
```

Now to make a prediction I embed the text vectorization layer in a "new" model:

```
input = keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype="string")
processed_input = self._text_vectorizer(input)
outputs = model(processed_input)
inference_model = keras.Model(input, outputs)
```

And finally:

```
raw_input = tf.convert_to_tensor([
    ["Some text to run the prediction on"],
])
predictions = inference_model(raw_input)
print(predictions[0])
```

Now, how do I convert the vectorized output in predictions[0] to a readable string?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
vocab = text_vectorizer.get_vocabulary()
" ".join([vocab[each] for each in tf.squeeze(predictions)])
```

Comment: Mmmm I've tried but I'm a bit lost. The prediction is of type float32, even if I explicitely set the output mode to "int" in the text vectorizer. I thought it might be the model converting ints to floats, but I've even flattened it to simple dense layers and I still get floats out. Converting the float to an int give an out of range error, do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Take the float output of your model and typecast everything to int. When it is int, try the above thing